# Ongoin use of variable in Worker class Android

Tags: android, kotlin, workmanagers

Im trying to perform a one time work with the worker class
where the doWork method will just count a number
Call it I.
This will loop through 100 times, and in every iteration, the counter will continue grow up.

I added a  constraint for this work to be network Constraining  connected.

I would like to count every time and if I close the Network the count will stop.
After I open the network I would like **The count to continue work from the same count
value that was there before**

Every time I close the network and open it again the count starts from zero again and the value that was in the counter before didn't save in the global variable I that I defined in the worker. it's like not taking the last value that was defined there.

My worker class

```
class WorkerClass(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
    Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
    var i:Int=0
     override fun doWork(): Result {

         while (i < 100) {
             if (this.isStopped){
                 Log.i("Hello","I Stopped A")
                     return Result.retry()
             }
             i++
             Log.i("Hello", "The value of counter is :"+i.toString())
             Thread.sleep(200)
         }
        return Result.success()
     }
}
```

My simple work creator: (There is a data passed I don't use it right now so you can ignore it.

```
 val constrints=Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()

        val k = sceondTxt.text.toString()
        val data=Data.Builder()
        data.putString("Counter Value",k)
        val oneReq:WorkRequest= OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<WorkerClass>().setConstraints(constrints).setInputData(data.build())
            .build()
```

So as you can  see I define an I as Integer and every iteration of the work the I is growing. but when I close the connection and open it again the I is 0 again and didn't save from the last run of doWork.

does the definition of i is not global? the system wont take the last value of I that was stored in the doWork for later iterations?

How can I save the value of something in my doWork to later use it again (after the constraints are met) not as the default value?

Comment: You are setting counter value in `Data` like `data.putString("Counter Value",k)` .  why don't use it in `WorkerClass`?

Comment: I tried using it in the workClass but this value is not updated. After the forst time i initial this value it doesnt getting update therfore i didnt use it. should i usd it? after work is stopped entire workClass get killed??

Comment: You can save counter in `shared preference`

Comment: but i cant create the Shared Preferences instance in Work class, how  can I pass the context in the working class?

Comment: You don't need to pass `Context` in `WorkingClass` , `WorkingClass` has `Context`